# RelativeLayout in Android: Widget dont show up

Tags: android-layout

I'm having trouble with RelativeLayout. I want to show a Button in the bottom of the Layout screen, but it is not shown.

See the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUO5a.png

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SABORES EXISTENTES"
    android:id="@+id/textViewNovoSabor"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#0501e5" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/rowsContainerControleSabor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewNovoSabor"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/rowsContainerControleSabor">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddNewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_background"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Adicionar sabor"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rowsContainerControleSabor"
        />
</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried all options i know.. I used the android:layout_below to set position, now its hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear layout for your listview is taking up the rest of the real estate with `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, so the button is pushed off the screen.

To solve this, take your button and lay it out at the bottom of the relative layout parent. Then build the listview linear layout on top of the button. Something like the following. This may not be exactly what you want, but it will get you mostly there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNovoSabor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SABORES EXISTENTES"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#0501e5" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rowsContainerControleSabor"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- This is the key idea along with placement of the button layout. -->
    android:layout_above="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewNovoSabor"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    <!-- This is the key idea. -->
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddNewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rowsContainerControleSabor"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Adicionar sabor"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it gave me a error: Resource cannot be found: "@idmyButton", so i removed the first LinearLayout and put the "layout_above with @idMyButton" direct in the ListView and it worked.